# How to use same sql query for multiple where clause in a procedure

Tags: sql

Query #1

```
SELECT 
    @IN_EMPCOUNT = COUNT (a.CH_EMPCODE) 
FROM 
    BSC_REVIEW_EMP_MASTER a
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.cmn_authorization b ON (CASE b.vc_bu WHEN '%' THEN a.BUSSCD ELSE b.vc_bu END) =  a.BUSSCD           
WHERE 
    IN_REVIEW_NO = @in_review_no
    AND b.ch_empcode = @ch_empcode  
    AND b.in_rolecode IN (136, 137, 138)
```

Query #2

```
SELECT 
    @IN_EMPCOUNT1 = COUNT (a.CH_EMPCODE) 
FROM 
    BSC_REVIEW_EMP_MASTER a
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.cmn_authorization b ON (CASE b.vc_bu WHEN '%' THEN a.BUSSCD ELSE b.vc_bu END) =  a.BUSSCD           
WHERE 
    IN_REVIEW_NO = @in_review_no
    AND b.ch_empcode = @ch_empcode  
    AND b.in_rolecode IN (138, 139, 140)
```

Query #3

```
SELECT 
    @IN_EMPCOUNT2 = COUNT (a.CH_EMPCODE) 
FROM 
    BSC_REVIEW_EMP_MASTER a
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.cmn_authorization b ON (CASE b.vc_bu WHEN '%' THEN a.BUSSCD ELSE b.vc_bu END) =  a.BUSSCD           
WHERE 
    IN_REVIEW_NO = @in_review_no
    AND b.ch_empcode = @ch_empcode  
    AND b.in_rolecode IN (141, 142, 145)
```

Result:

```
Select @in_empcount, @in_empcount1, @in_empcount2
```

This is an example query on which I am working on. Can I do something like don't have to repeat the same select statements for every where clause `for (b.in_rolecode)` and result would be the same?

Comment: Can you supply sample data and desired results -- not sure I'm understanding your question.

Comment: Also, please indicate what SQL product you are using and tag the question accordingly. There are subtle syntax differences between SQL products.

Comment: @rohitsingh - So all three query would give different result. So what do you want now? Want all result in single query?

Comment: @rohitsingh What database product are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're asking -- including all those values in your `IN` clause:

```
select name 
from tabl1 
where id in ( 1,2,3,4,8,9 )
```

The IN clause works just like an OR clause, so no need to separate those queries.

*EDIT -- Based on your newest edits, you're looking to use CASE and COUNT (you could also use SUM, but it works the same way):*

```
SELECT 
    COUNT (CASE WHEN b.in_rolecode IN (136,137,138) THEN 1 END) in_empcount,
    COUNT (CASE WHEN b.in_rolecode IN (138,139,140) THEN 1 END) in_empcount1,
    COUNT (CASE WHEN b.in_rolecode IN (141,142,145) THEN 1 END) in_empcount2
FROM BSC_REVIEW_EMP_MASTER a
    INNER JOIN dbo.cmn_authorization b
         ON (CASE b.vc_bu WHEN '%' THEN a.BUSSCD ELSE b.vc_bu END) =  a.BUSSCD           
WHERE IN_REVIEW_NO = @in_review_no
    AND b.ch_empcode =@ch_empcode
```

Comment: No i want all the results in different columns according to the condition

Comment: @rohitsingh -- see edits above -- thanks for posting your actual queries.

Comment: @rohitsingh -- np, glad I could help!